# Ubuntu on USB keeps asking to install on hdd

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb-drive

I used the Pendrive universal USB installer to create a live USB w/Ubuntu  I can boot fine and everything works but everytime I boot it asks if I want to install to the HDD.  I choose no but it takes a long time to load from there.  Is it possible to skip the install selection screen?  This is for personal use of my work laptop and while Linux via USB is acceptable, install to HDD is not permitted.

Comment: You can install Ubuntu on USB drive then use it everywhere. You don't need pendrive installer.

Comment: The answer you are looking for is here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LiveUsbPendrivePersistent